# bash: /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys: No such file or directory

Tags: command-line, ssh

Create a ssh key:
Command:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ""
```

Moving the key to authorized key:
Command:

```
cat $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
bash: /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys: No such file or directory
```

Comment: `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` are keys of other computers that you connected to/trust, not your **own** key.

Comment: Some applications require passwordless ssh to one's own machine.

Comment: Please don't post the same question on [multiple sites](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/129573/22222) of the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Why you need to trust the key you own? Exactly what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 113):

You have to create the `.ssh` directory and the `authorized_keys` file the first time.

1. Create the `.ssh` directory:

   ```
   mkdir ~/.ssh
   ```
2. Set the right permissions:

   ```
   chmod 700 ~/.ssh
   ```
3. Create the `authorized_keys` file:

   ```
   touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
   ```
4. Set the right permissions:

   ```
   chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
   ```

The permissions are important! It won't work without the right permissions!

Now you can add the **public key** to the `authorized_keys` file:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

---

You have to add the public key of **your computer** to the `authorized_keys` file of the **computer you want to access using SSH Keys**!

---

As terdon mentioned you can also just use this command:

```
ssh-copy-id user@host
```

This will put your `id_rsa.pub` (in your `~/.ssh` directory) in the remote computer's `authorized_keys` file, creating the `.ssh` directory and `authorized_keys` file with the right permissions if necessary.

Comment: In any case, you don't want to just `cat` it, that's what `ssh-copy-id` is for.

Comment: Wow, cool, I've added it.

Comment: @LouisMatthijssen I have copied keys to my remote server. How can I confirm that the public key is added in authorized_keys.

Comment: In my case `authorzed_keys` is named `known_hosts`.
And after `chmod`s it works! thx

Answer (score 4):

Since I don't have enough reputation, I'm adding this here.
In addition to Louis Matthijssen's answer if you are still not able to login through ssh as a user that you've created, like

```
ssh username@host
```

then this may be because of the absence of **owner permission** that you must add to your /home/username/.ssh folder. I had the same issue and you can give this permission as:

```
chown -R username:username /home/username/.ssh
```

This can probably happen simply because you were creating the directory and setting the permissions as **root**, but not as the **username** you want to access the server with.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

In case you have been sent the public key in an email to install to a remote server:

1) SSH into the server. I used PuTTY on Windows.

2) Setup the key:

```
mkdir ~/.ssh
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
vi ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Take care to copy the key exactly and paste it into a new line in the editor window. Verify that it occupies a single line and save.

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 touch $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

to create empty file with the rights of that user.

This file is created when you access  for the first a remote host with that user.

Answer (score 0):

This can also fail if, when creating the key with `ssh-keygen`, you give it a filename. I entered some name `my-ssh-file-name`, and it wrote the key to `/Users/MyUserName` instead of the `.ssh` folder. If you leave the filename blank, it will write to `.ssh` as expected.